# Can i use an array of uchars as a single uchar?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a LZW compressor that records its output in hexadecimal. It currently uses an uchar (OpenCV) for storing values, and outputs the uchar in hexadecimal.

However, I have been asked to allow the user to choose how many bytes are used when storing each value, so he could have, for example, 2 bytes for each value (or 32 bytes, it's up to him).

So, to manipulate the output, I was thinking of using an array of uchars (so, if the user asks for 32 bytes, I use an array of 32 uchars), and the question is: is there an easy way to write a big value to this array and outputting that value later without having to worry about what is in what index and other things? That is, to treat the array as just a x byte uchar? Should I use a vector?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not very clear what you're asking, but what you want to do sounds similar to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: There is no standard `uchar` type, I recommend you use the standard `uint8_t` instead if you want a small unsigned integer.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV, forgot to add

Comment: As for your problem, can you please elaborate on it? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I'm not talking about how to make your solution work, but the original reason that made you come up with this solution.

Comment: Okay, here goes:
I'm programming an LZW compressor. It compresses images based on patterns. It already works when using a fixed size for the output, such as 1 byte. However, i was asked to allow the user to choose how many bytes are stored for each value in the output. This allows the program to store more patterns, but generates a larger file and uses more memory.

Comment: If the size was decided at compile-time it would be easy to use a `typedef` to get the correct type. But if it's done at run-time then perhaps a union of the possible alternative types? Or just overloaded functions that takes different types, and which one you initially call depends on the user choice?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this union of possible alternative types? I've never heard of that. I'm not sure if i'm trying to do it already but failing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following union

```
union pun_unsigned {
  unsigned char c[sizeof(uint64_t)];
  uint16_t u16;
  uint32_t u32;
  uint64_t u64;
};
```

Note that only conversions from or to (signed or unsigned) char are defined behaviour.